# WordPress - Get Database results with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Good morning!  I'm just trying out AJAX in a WordPress plugin for the first time, and I'm a bit stumped.

Basically, I have 2 divs next to each other.  Left one has a list of cell phone numbers, right one should contain the conversation with the cell number that the user clicks on.  (it will look a lot like the messaging app on an iPad). 
I don't want to re-load the page to switch to a different conversation, so I thought this was a good plan.  Correct me if I'm wrong!

So I've got this HTML: (abbreviated for simplicity)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="list_cell_numbers">
    <a href="" class="ajax-link" id="1238675309">123-867-5309</a>
    <a href="" class="ajax-link" id="9035768321">903-576-8321</a>
  </div>

  <div class="show_conversation">
    <!--Display Database Results Here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  $(".ajax-link").click( function() {
    var data = {
      action: 'sms_load_conversation',
      cell_number: $(this).attr('id')
    };

  $.post('http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data,
    function(response) {
      alert(response)
    });

  });

});
```

Here is my Wordpress Function that handles the AJAX call:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_sms_load_conversation', 'sms_load_conversation');
function sms_load_conversation() {
  global $wpdb;
  if( isset( $_POST["cell_number"] ) ) {
    $number = $_POST["cell_number"];
    $msgs = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT message, sent_date FROM sms_log WHERE cell_number = $number LIMIT 1");

    echo $msgs->message;

    wp_die();
  }
}
```

So with this code I have gotten to the point where I can click on the link, and the proper result is returned - the message from the database.  Where I'm stuck is: 
1- how to actually place this content into my "show_conversation" div on the page once it's returned, and
2- how can I have the AJAX respond with multiple database results with multiple fields?  I feel like I need to have the sms_load_conversation function get the db results, format the results as HTML and return the entire HTML back to my "show_conversation" div, but I'm not entirely sure how I would go about returning that much information.  Is it just one HUGE string?

Thank you so much in advance if anyone can offer some direction!!!

Comment: you need to quoted your post data `WHERE cell_number = '".$number."'`

Comment: The query is working fine, I get the results expected.  What I am unsure of is how I can get the entire `$msgs` array returned to my original page for parsing.  OR - if I parse the entire array in the `sms_load_conversation` function, then how do I return the entire HTML code to my original page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the jQuery code, modify the .post() response like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  $(".ajax-link").click( function() {
    var data = {
      action: 'sms_load_conversation',
      cell_number: $(this).attr('id')
    };
    $.post(
      'http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data,
      function(response) {
        $('.show_conversation').html(response);
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! I clearly have some learning to do regarding javascript!